# Contributing to open source bundles from vendor directory?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

**Ideal Situation**

Often while working on a Symfony2 project I will spot something I want to change in one of my dependencies. If I could find a way to simply change it in vendor and then easily push the changes as a pull request then I would probably contribute more often (rather than overriding the part with a local child bundle).

**The Problem**

I can't change a vendor directory without composer freaking out on the next update. If I submit a pull request then it may take quite some time before I can actually use the code in vendors, which is actually a deterrent from contributing my new functionality.

**How I do it now**

The way I typically contribute to a bundle is to make a fork, put the fork in a barebones symfony standard-edition app, make the change and then submit a pull request.

**Put fork in `composer.json`?**

The only solution I can think of, is removing the packagist dependency of the bundle I am editing, and then including my fork with composer (as a package) from github. That way I get my code immediately and can still contribute.

Is this the only solution? How do you do it?

Any tips/advice for contributing to a bundle while working on a different project at the same time would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you have it right. There's 2 parts: submitting the patch and using the patch. I usually fork/branch the package in my working project to make the fix. Commit it and push it to my own repo. Then if i want to keep using that fix i'll add that reference to my fork/branch to composer.

Comment: We use the same approach as @MDrollette. First we use the standard packages. If something needs fixing (like the DBAL QueryBuilder - https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/175), we fork it, use our fork instead of the standard one, modify code, write tests and open a pull request hoping that the fix gets included.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[UPDATE: Answer Not Valid Anymore]**

As pointed out in one of the comments, this answer is a couple years old and not correct anymore. See answers below for the correct way to proceed.

**[Original answer below]**

This is the approach recommended by Jordi Boggiano (@Seldaek), creator of composer.
See from his talk at Symfony Live San Francisco earlier this year (at the 2 minutes mark):
http://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLo7mBDsRHu11ChvScWUE7MN1Qo5QVHQEz&feature=player_detailpage&v=P3NwF8RV1lY#t=120s

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This is the only way I've tried that retrieves the fork and works with dependencies. Rather than using the https form for the repository as shown in the video I use this form. It doesn't require a password- git@github.com:<user>/<module-name>.git  The key to satisfying dependencies is inline aliasing.

Comment: outdated information, see below for correct answer for this specific issue as of Oct 2016

Answer (score 55):

Nah... this is broken.

I've tried the official way to include a fork, here's an example (original:kitano, fork: jstoeffler) of the composer.json :

(**For those who are in a hurry: THIS DOESNT WORK)**

```
"repositories": [
//...
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/jstoeffler/KitanoConnectionBundle",

    },
//...
],
```

**It keeps using the original bundle**. Don't know what the problem is, and I don't get how everything works, but here's how I successfully add a fork to a project.

```
"repositories": [
//...
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "kitano/connection-bundle",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/jstoeffler/KitanoConnectionBundle.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            },
            "autoload": {
                "classmap": [""]
            }
        }
    },
//...
],
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternate method.

Comment: Just want to add that it is nice to have an alternate method, but **the official method does work** (I've just use it today with an up-to-date composer installation). I've just needed to append the *dev-* prefix in front of my forked branch name and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @mTorres that did not work for me, unfortunately. Julien's did.

Comment: From what Im understanding, if your branch is out of date with the master branch and that other modules require the up to date original, the official method doesn't work.

Comment: Just to clarify for others (since this slipped me up), the `reference` value should be the name of your branch excluding the `dev-` prefix.

Comment: The original method works for me when I "tagged" the forked version and incremented the version - so I could specifically target it with my composer. i.e. from 1.1.0 to 1.2.0

Comment: The "For those who are in a hurry" method works fine for me when also specifying that you want the `dev-master` version. This pulls in the fork.

Comment: Unfortunately this just clones the repository but doesn't require the compose.json dependencies in that repository

Comment: if the original repo already has a branch with a `dev-`-prefix or if its a fork itself, this method is not working. instead, do an own fork of the repo, create a new branch like "mynewbranch" from the branch you need, and require it with `dev-mynewbranch`

Answer (score 7):

As of 2017 the proper way to do it is:

1. Add your GitHub branch link to the `repositories`

   ```
   "repositories": [
       {
           "type": "vcs",
           "url": "https://github.com/crimson-med/yii2-link-preview"
       }
   ],
   ```
2. Add the source to the `require` of your `composer.json`

   ```
   "require": {
       "yii2mod/yii2-link-preview": "dev-master"
   },
   ```

Answer (score 2):

FYI, I just tried the very first option:

```
    "repositories": [{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/thujohn/twitter"
}],
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "thujohn/twitter": "dev-master",
    "anahkiasen/flickering": "^0.1.2",
    "fairholm/elasticquent": "dev-master",
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "~5.0"
},
```

An it worked fine.

```
vagrant@dev:/var/www$ sudo php composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information                                                                                                                                                         Updating dependencies (including require-dev)         
  - Removing thujohn/twitter (2.0.4)
  - Installing thujohn/twitter (dev-master 7a92118)
    Downloading: 100%         

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
```

I just needed to specify the "master" branch name as "dev-master".