# How to require a fork with composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

This is my `composer.json`, I want to use Nodge's fork of lessphp project on Github

```json
 "repositories": [{
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
        "version": "dev-master",
        "name": "nodge/lessphp",
        "source": {
            "url": "https://github.com/Nodge/lessphp.git",
            "type": "git",
            "reference": "master"
        },
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": ["lessc.inc.php"]
        }
    }
}],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "nodge/lessphp": "dev-master"
},
```

But I get this error when I run `composer update`:

> nodge/lessphp dev-master -> no matching package found.

I don't know how to require correctly this fork.

Answer (score 309, accepted):

The most common (and easiest) way of doing it is using a VCS repository.

> All you have to do is add your fork as a repository and update the
> version constraint to point to your custom branch. Your custom branch
> name **must** be prefixed with **`dev-`**.

Assuming you forked **monolog/monolog** and created a branch called **bugfix**, you would update your composer.json like this:

```json
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/igorw/monolog"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "dev-bugfix"
    }
}
```

Note that you don't change the require statement except to specify your bugfix branch. You still reference the upstream package (`monolog/monolog`), *not* your personal fork (`igorw/monolog`), and the branch name is prefixed with `dev-`. You can read details [in the docs](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for https://github.com/Polycademy/purl which is a fork of https://github.com/jwage/purl I've been trying to:

 "repositories": [
  {
   "type": "vcs",
   "url": "git@github.com:Polycademy/purl.git"
  }
 ],

and 

 "require": {
  "jwade/purl": "dev-master",
 },

But I keep getting:

 Problem 1
    - The requested package jwade/purl could not be found in any version, there
may be a typo in the package name.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai try running `composer show jwade/purl -v` it should tell you why it ignored the dev-master version if it does.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai You must get the right github subversion url clicking un "Subversion" near the repo url field.

Comment: @seldaek you saved me! thank you! ( My fork was called dev-dev-.. ) didn't know the naming was automatically.

Comment: composer show is the key to find the name of the branch! thanks @Seldaek

Comment: "Read the docs" is a bad answer, a better answer would be to give a concrete example

Comment: Nice to warn about not referencing to personal fork. This saved my day, +1

Comment: Your branch name does not need to add `dev-` you will end up duplicated dev-dev- when you require in composer.json file. This is why our master branch when you required in composer.json, you have added in as `dev-master`

Comment: this isn't working for me, and unfortunately i'm using someone else's work so i don't get to rename their branch (and i'm too lazy to fork a fork.. just saying that makes my jaw hurt).. details [here](https://github.com/maknz/slack-laravel/pull/11#issuecomment-360841508)

Comment: Any way to _not_ need a GitHub OAuth token for this solution? I'm trying this solution, but it's asking me for an OAuth token to go over the API rate limit. I don't want to need to do that on every environment I deploy to.

Comment: Apparently, the package name to use in the `require` entry needs to be the one defined in the `name` entry of the fork's `composer.json` file. Fork authors can choose to change or to keep the identifier.

Comment: thanks @ÁlvaroGonzález I was struggling as the original author changed his name but in composer.json was the original name ..

Comment: @CGriffin did you ever figure out how to get around the rate limit? When I composer require using this method it looks like it's hitting every single version, it takes forever, and I hit my rate limit every single time.

Comment: What if a package has the package I'm overwriting as a dependency, then using dev-master doesn't work it says it doesn't match the constraints

Answer (score 53):

Using VCS works:

```json
"name": "test/test",
"repositories": [{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "http://github.com/Nodge/lessphp"
}],
"require": {
    "leafo/lessphp": "dev-master"
},
```

But if I require a module that has this `composer.json`, it doesn't work. It installs the original project, not the fork.

### Example

```json
"name": "example/example",
"require": {
    "test/test": "dev-master"
},
```

I should mention again the repository. Is that normal?

Comment: same here same problem

Comment: Manually delete the module using "rm -rf" and then "composer update". That worked for me.

Comment: I've used a dozen of forks, and **this never worked**. Here's a working solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27970559/183904

Comment: @Julien, I've just used this method and it worked like a charm... The [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs) are quite clear, you must only remember to put the *dev-* prefix in your custom branch name when requiring the package in question.

Comment: Worked for me... but I want to mention that I needed to use https:// for the URL.

Comment: I solved this by "tagging" a new version on my fork - i.e. from 1.1.0 to 1.2.0 - and that allowed me to solve the issue

Answer (score 48):

If you can't get @Neilime answer to work for you, make sure your fork uses a different branch.

For example push your changes to a branch on your fork called `my-bugfix`, do not added `dev-` prefix in your branch name but in your composer.json you have to add it. Your composer file will look like:

```
"repositories":
[
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "http://github.com/yourname/packageName"
    }
],
"require": {
    "owner/packageName": "dev-my-bugfix"
},
```

Comment: This is ingenious and clear explanation for me ! Thank You !

Comment: but what if it's someone _else's_ fork? See example [here](https://github.com/maknz/slack-laravel/pull/11#issuecomment-360841508)

Comment: Also, `name` field in your forked repository's `composer.json` file should stay the same with the original owner.

Answer (score 20):

I have tried many options but After I got this post I saw the light and it just worked perfect.

This is what you have to do:

1- Fork The repository

2- Create a branch and make the required modifications.

3- Add the repository label to your composer.json

```
"repositories": [
     
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/user/yourforkname"
        }
    ]
```

4- In the command line inside your project require your fork like this:

```
composer require vendor/packagename:dev-branchname
```

And Voilá!!

You have your fork version working

Answer (score 7):

According to the Composer documentation
http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs, it's enough to
 specify the original repository (not the fork) in the `require` ("nodge/lessphp" in your case). Composer will then install YOUR fork (look at the code in the vendors)

Answer (score 7):

So, this is 2019, and most of the answers here are already correct.

If you find yourself however, in a situation where you need to require a **particular branch** of your fork (that you created), have composer list the available versions/tags first.
This saved me a lot of time.

A full example with `spatie/laravel-backup` package.

First, add `repositories` key to composer.json. With the url of your fork

```
"repositories": [{
   "type": "vcs",
   "url": "https://github.com/holymp2006/laravel-backup"
 }]
```

Get available versions/tags

```
composer show "spatie/laravel-backup" --all
```

Choose the version you want from `versions` in the terminal output, then require that version

```
composer require spatie/laravel-backup:v5.x-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually add a "dist" node to the package definition.
I never had a problem using it this way.

I can't remember where I got this trick from, though, for any further explanations.

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "version": "dev-master",
                "name": "nodge/lessphp",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/Nodge/lessphp.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "classmap": ["lessc.inc.php"]
                },
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/Nodge/lessphp/archive/master.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "nodge/lessphp": "*"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer and clarifying answers all worked well for me when I had ex. an **application**, which needed a dependency I had forked and modified. I’d still use the accepted answer in this case.

However, when I had a **package** I wanted to distribute myself on Packagist, which also contained a forked and modified dependency, this approach no longer worked.

If someone were to try and install with this config, they’ll still get that same  `-> no matching package found.` error message.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567656/composer-no-matching-package-found) and the [linked Composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can%27t-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md) suggest that the repo settings have to be at the top-level `composer.json`. That means, someone installing this package would have to add that config to their `composer.json` file too—which adds a lot of unnecessary confusion to the install process.

Instead, I published my fork to Packagist. My understanding is that while forks are frowned upon, this would be considered a maintained fork, since I am using it for this new package.

Hopefully that’s helpful for anyone who has this problem with a package or library they’d like to distribute.

Comment: Stumbeling over the exact same issue (hard to google) and I can confirm the problem