# composer.json not loading forked repo

Tags: laravel, github, composer-php, fork

I used [How to require a fork with composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498519/how-to-require-a-fork-with-composer/13508823#13508823) and https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs to come up with the composer.json file below. I forked a lib to update the composer.json file and it is not loading mine. It is loading the original repo.

```
 "repositories": [{
  "type": "vcs",
  "url": "https://github.com/Dylan-Buth/gopher"
}],
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "~5.0",
    "indatus/gopher": "1.*"
},
```

Comment: I changed it to `"indatus/gopher": "*"` and it ran through completely. Any clue why?

Comment: Has a newer version been added to packagist? That would override your fork.

Comment: The latest version from the "Indatus" is 1.1 . Would my fork count as a different version or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even after you fork the repository, composer will still try to resolve version `1.*`. So it will get your forked repository, but it will look up the latest `1.*` version. Even if you put `*` as the version requirement, it will still get the latest *tag*, not the latest commit.

If you want the latest commit, you can put `dev-master` as the required version string. Alternatively you could modify the `composer.json` in your *forked* package to "alias" the version you want:

```
{
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am confused by the down-votes on this question but thanks for the response. Worked for me!