# Laravel 5 packages, how to develop over?

Tags: git, version-control, package, laravel-5, composer-php

I have one question about the Laravel 5 packages and packages in general.

I install the pingpong/admin for laravel, a good part of files goes to /vendor directory that have the gitignore for the version control.

My question is: Okay i get the package and it's work well, but now i wont to develop over this package, change some thing, add some thing and finally commit all the staff and go further, what are the best practice for do it?

I need to copy/paste all files to the laravel /app/Http folder maybe in /app/Http/AdminApp and after i can commit all the staff ... or i need to create my new file extend the functionality of installed package and commit only my changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to modify some package to your need, you can send [pull-request on Github](https://github.com/pingpong-labs/admin) or fork it, modify it and then [require your fork in your `composer.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498519/how-to-require-a-fork-with-composer).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! No i not only need to modify a package, i wont to use this package for develop my application, the package have a good start functionality but i need to change and add some things.

Comment: If you need to change lot of things, I'd recommend you forking the package. Also some package allows extending it's functionality quite easily, so there is no need to modify the package. Not sure what's the situation for your package though.