# How can I contribute to a third-party Symfony bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to add a missing feature to a bundle. Here is what I've done so far:

- Spoke to the project owner and got their approval
- Created a fork and cloned it locally into a directory outside of my project
- Made a feature branch
- Ran `composer install`

Now, the question is, how can I include this into my own Symfony project so that it would be autoloaded? I want to test my changes inside my own project before I send a pull request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [How to require a fork with composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498519/how-to-require-a-fork-with-composer), to be specific, require a VCS repository as described in [Composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs)

Or a bit faster way for improving developing process (which is independent on Github), try [using local repositories](http://www.glatter-gotz.com/blog/2014/04/09/php-composer-working-with-local-repositories/).

Comment: So my workflow would be to add my repository to `composer.json`, and then edit->`git commit`->`git push`->`composer update`->test->repeat?

Comment: Yes. There is also faster way [using local repositories](http://www.glatter-gotz.com/blog/2014/04/09/php-composer-working-with-local-repositories/) (I've added it to my answer).

Answer (score 3):

You can archive in two manner:

1. You can hack the vendor folder replacing the folder of the bundle with a symlink of the third-party bundle
2. [RECOMENDED] Put in the composer.json file of your project the reference of your personal github project instead of the official version

Comment: I've voted for the other answer, but I admit that more often than not I use the trick of the symlink in the `vendor/` directory.

Comment: Hi @JavierEguiluz i also voted for the other answer: more complete and documented. I read also the ability to do the same trick via composer with the [artifact](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#artifact) options!