# Laravel 5.2 Extend Package

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want  to make some changes on laravel package away from vendor folder   But I didn't found the best . If you know please point me

Comment: If you want to modify the laravel source code, then it's here https://github.com/laravel/laravel

Comment: thank you for your interest . i want to modify this  package  https://github.com/jdavidbakr/mail-tracker                                            and use it in laravel project

Comment: do you mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13500676/4233593