# Requiring Forked Version In Composer

Tags: git, github, composer-php

I have read this in countless other places, but for some reason, this doesn't appear to be working for me.  It never pulls the version from the forked repo?  Here is what I am trying to pull:  https://github.com/Jafo232/laravel-medialibrary/tree/v3

Here is my composer file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/Jafo232/laravel-medialibrary"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.2",
        "ixudra/curl": "^6.10",
        "jenssegers/model": "^1.1",
        "laracasts/flash": "^2.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "v3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {

        "sort-packages": true
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to remove the package from the `vendor` folder and `composer install` again? Also the version in `composer.json` is using the `tag` names not the `branch` names. So with requiring `v3` you should end up at tag `3.0.0` but not on branch `v3`.

Comment: I tried all of that with no luck.

Comment: At least following this should work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13500676/3219613