# Composer: install package fork

Tags: php, composer-php

I've forked a composer package so I can fix an issue with it and submit a PR to the maintainer.

Meanwhile, while it doesn't get merged, I want to use my version of the package in my projects. I've tried adding the repository information on `composer.json` but it always uses the regular package.

How can I force it to use my version? Do I have to rename the package?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share what exactly you've changed

Comment: I've changed some package code... Don't really think the source code influences this behavior.

Comment: No, you should share how you've changed the `composer.json` such that others can check these changes for an error

Comment: I haven't made any changes in `composer.json`. I just added a repository definition in the `composer.json` file of projects that use the package. My question is exactly that: do I have to change the package name in the package's `composer.json` so it can be installed?

Comment: @GonçaloMarrafa You have to amend the package name if you want to publish it on packagist. For example `marrafa/mypackage`.  Or - epxlictly define the fork as a repo in the `composer.json` where you want to use the package.

Comment: If you don't change anything in your `composer.json`, how should Composer know about that new package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading a composer package through a Github fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377221/loading-a-composer-package-through-a-github-fork)

Comment: @NicoHaase I added a repo in `composer.json` like @madflow suggested. Shouldn't composer be aware of it?

Comment: Well, that depends on **how** you've done that. As long as we cannot see how **exactly** you've changed the configuration, we can only guess

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out! I had a constraint on stable versions so it would not install a dev version and that was why it wouldn't read my fork.

Btw, no changes are required on the package's `composer.json` file. It treats it as the regular upstream package.

Answer (score 0):

so, your forked package is on github for example. so, just use it:

composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "mygithub/blabla": 1.0
},
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:mygithub/blabla.git"
        }
]
```

more info can be found [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is... it's not "my package". It's a fork of `foo/package`. The package already exists in packagist. I just want to use my version of it.