# how to use a substitute repository for a dependency's dependency in Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, tcpdf, html2pdf

this is my composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "spipu/html2pdf": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

now, `spipu/html2pdf` depends on `tecnickcom/TCPDF`, but i would like to use the [`patch-1` branch of `divinity76/TCPDF`](https://github.com/divinity76/TCPDF/tree/patch-1) as a substitute for `tecnickcom/TCPDF`, how can i do that?

(here's the problem: there's a unicode bug? limitation? in tecnickcom/TCPDF , making it impossible to generate PDF files with unicode filenames, like `aæøå.pdf`. [i have sent a fix pull request](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/pull/59) , but it's been over 2 months with no response from the upstream maintainer :( i tried emailing tecnickcom too, but no response )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13500676/4621324

Comment: @Axalix seems relevant yes, but changing my composer.json to [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/TRBimyRg) , gives [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/pLxuArPf) error when running `composer update` ... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the link posted by Axalix in a comment, i found out i could substitute 1 repository with another, with the `repositories` property in composer.json , however, this substitute repository will not load tags that don't already exist in the original repository, just branches. however, spipu/html2pdf specifically requires version `~6.2`, which makes composer refuse to install any dev-branch... but with the `as` keyword, i can substitute any branch with any version too, with that in mind, this seems to work:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/divinity76/TCPDF.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "spipu/html2pdf": "dev-master",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "dev-patch-1 as 6.2.13"
    }
}
```

i found the branch-version substitution solution (the `as` keyword) here http://mnapoli.fr/overriding-dependencies-with-composer/

and the repository substitution solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13500676/1067003 (linked to by Axalix )