# Install unstable fork

Tags: composer-php

I maintain a project that uses an [abandoned library](https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader) with a bug that affects me. I'd like to install [a fork](https://github.com/virtua-network/spreadsheet-reader) that includes the bugfix. I can't find the way.

Relevant settings were this:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": "5.3 - 5.6",
        "nuovo/spreadsheet-reader": "^0.5.11"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "vendor-dir": "Vendor/"
    }
}
```

I've tried too many things to share but my latest iteration is:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/virtua-network/spreadsheet-reader"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "5.3 - 5.6",
        "nuovo/spreadsheet-reader": "dev-master"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "vendor-dir": "Vendor/"
    }
}
```

The package shows up in `composer outdated`:

```
PS D:\src> composer outdated
nuovo/spreadsheet-reader             0.5.11   dev-master f6bd49d Spreadsheet reader library for Excel, OpenOffice and structured text files
```

… but won't update:

```
PS D:\src> composer update nuovo/spreadsheet-reader
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Also, `f6bd49d` hash is not [latest fork revision](https://github.com/virtua-network/spreadsheet-reader/commits/master) but [latest original package](https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader/commits/master).

How can I install the fork with Composer?

Comment: Did you tried to change constraints to `"nuovo/spreadsheet-reader": "dev-master"`?

Comment: @rob006 Yes, I did. I've edited question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using incorrect package name - in your fork package is named as `virtua-network/spreadsheet-reader`, but you're requesting `nuovo/spreadsheet-reader`. So your fork is **not** considered as a `nuovo/spreadsheet-reader` package, but as a `virtua-network/spreadsheet-reader`, so original package from Packagist is used. You should either revert [name change](https://github.com/virtua-network/spreadsheet-reader/commit/7657512fe99345e2b756fb78b9cfdc7349ce9d4c) in `composer.json` of your fork and leave it as `nuovo/spreadsheet-reader`, or use new name in `require` of `composer.json` in your app:

```
"virtua-network/spreadsheet-reader": "dev-master"
```

Comment: Thank you! I did so and then `composer require virtua-network/spreadsheet-reader` and `composer remove nuovo/spreadsheet-reader`. I was using the upstream package name because that's what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13500676/13508) says and it actually worked for me in another project with another package set. Now I understand that the name that counts is the one in the forks's `composer.json` file.