# How to require fork of composer repo with conflicting requirements?

Tags: composer-php

So, I followed Saldeak's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498519/how-to-require-a-fork-with-composer). I want to use my own fork in a project of the repo, however, during installation I get conflicting requirements.

```
$ composer update zfcampus/zf-content-validation
Loading composer repositories with package information                                                                                                                                                         Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin 1.6.0 requires zfcampus/zf-content-validation ^1.4 -> satisfiable by zfcampus/zf-content-validation[1.7.x-dev, 1.6.x-dev].
    - zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin 1.6.0 requires zfcampus/zf-content-validation ^1.4 -> satisfiable by zfcampus/zf-content-validation[1.7.x-dev, 1.6.x-dev].
    - zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin 1.6.0 requires zfcampus/zf-content-validation ^1.4 -> satisfiable by zfcampus/zf-content-validation[1.7.x-dev, 1.6.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: zfcampus/zf-content-validation[1.7.x-dev, dev-alias-and-remove-empty-data].
    - Can only install one of: zfcampus/zf-content-validation[1.6.x-dev, dev-alias-and-remove-empty-data].
    - Can only install one of: zfcampus/zf-content-validation[1.7.x-dev, dev-alias-and-remove-empty-data].
    - Can only install one of: zfcampus/zf-content-validation[1.6.x-dev, dev-alias-and-remove-empty-data].
    - Installation request for zfcampus/zf-content-validation dev-alias-and-remove-empty-data -> satisfiable by zfcampus/zf-content-validation[dev-alias-and-remove-empty-data].
    - Installation request for zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin (locked at 1.6.0, required as ^1.5.9) -> satisfiable by zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin[1.6.0].
```

In the `composer.json` I require this:

```
"zfcampus/zf-content-validation": "dev-alias-and-remove-empty-data",
```

And the repo has been added to the list:

```
{
  "type": "vcs",
  "url": "git@github.com:rkeet/zf-content-validation.git"
}
```

---

**I've tried to**

```
composer remove zfcampus/zf-content-validation
composer require zfcampus/zf-content-validation:dev-alias-and-remove-empty-data
```

And

```
composer remove zfcampus/zf-content-validation
composer update zfcampus/zf-content-validation
```

But every time this comes back to the above error.

---

Notes:

- Cannot "just delete" all vendors and `composer.lock` to install latest of everything; there are more requirements than just this one that are tested for the installed versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to alias your new branch as regular numeric branch, so it could be used to resolving requirements of other dependencies.

```
"zfcampus/zf-content-validation": "dev-alias-and-remove-empty-data as 1.7.x-dev",
```

After this Composer will treat  your branch as `1.7` line, so it should match `^1.4` constraint.

See [Require inline alias](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#require-inline-alias) section in documentation.

Comment: Life saver! Hadn't yet come across that particular feature! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Quickly looked it up, could you add it to your answer? Direct link: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#require-inline-alias