# How to announce forked version in composer.json?

Tags: composer-php, git-fork

I have forked the package laravel-forum by riari and edited the branch 5.0 (that is not the main branch).

Now I want to use my fork within my composer.json file. Usually, when the forked branch is called master, I am using dev-master instead of master for my forked repositories (e.g. the42coders/eu-cookie-consent or highsolutions/laravel-translation-manager.

When I am using the main version by

```
"riari/laravel-forum": "~5.0"
```

everything is working fine, but now I didn't find a way to use my dev version:
Neither of them are working:

```
"riari/laravel-forum": "dev-master"

"riari/laravel-forum": "dev-5.0"

"riari/laravel-forum": "dev-~5.0"
```

The error message is saying:

*Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires riari/laravel-forum dev-master, found riari/laravel-forum[dev-laravel-4, dev-laravel-5, dev-5.0-feature-test-threads, dev-plural, 1.0.0, ..., 1.2.3, 2.0.0, ..., 2.5.0, 3.0.0-RC1, ..., 3.1.9, 4.0.0, ..., 4.1.5, 5.0.x-dev] but it does not match the constraint.*

What can I do to get it working?

```
    "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/tms1987/laravel-translation-manager"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/tms1987/eu-cookie-consent"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/tms1987/laravel-forum"
    }
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "highsolutions/laravel-translation-manager": "dev-master",
        "laravel-lang/lang": "~8.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.2",
        "riari/laravel-forum": "dev-5.0",
        "the42coders/eu-cookie-consent": "dev-master"
```

Comment: Okay, it's working now. I changed in my projects composer.json to "5.0.x-dev", which is actually name when i use composer show "riari/laravel-forum show --all". In the forked repos composer.json I had to correct the name (wrong name was given in the original repo). Also I added a branch-alias "dev-master":"5.0.x-dev".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to require a fork with composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498519/how-to-require-a-fork-with-composer)