# retrieving fork with composer

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

This has been discussed multiple times in multiple questions on SO, but all the answers given refuse to work for me accept this answer:

[Contributing to open source bundles from vendor directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325158/contributing-to-open-source-bundles-from-vendor-directory/27970559#27970559)

I've tested this on multiple machines, so I'm pretty sure it's not an isolated incident.

But using the type "package" is considered bad practice I read. Can someone explain to me why this is not working? It won't load the forked repository!

```
{
    "repositories":
    [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/flyandi/lumen-doctrine.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "nordsoftware/lumen-doctrine": "dev-master@dev"
    }
}
```

## update

So it turns out it has something todo with the stability of packages more about that here:

https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html

I then tried this which works:

```
{
    "repositories":
    [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/flyandi/lumen-doctrine.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "nordsoftware/lumen-doctrine": "dev-master@dev"
    },
    "prefer-stable" : true,
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

What I don't understand is way the @dev flag doesn't work though? Can someone elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer tries to resolve into a stable set of packages by default.
It won't resolve, because the package you are fetching (via alias) 
uses development dependencies itself. The dependency `doctrine/orm` of the package you are fetching `lumen-doctrine` is required in dev mode.
And the need for this development dependency bubbles up to your package.

When you add `dev-master` or `dev-master@dev` for `nordsoftware/lumen-doctrine`
it works only for this package. 
The `@dev` makes explicit, what we already know because of the `dev-` prefix: its a request for a dev version, but it doesn't change the stability for all packages - and it doesn't set the stability for dependencies of the package.

The installation request for `nordsoftware/lumen-doctrine`is satisfiable by  `dev-master` (and by a number of tagged versions).

The problem is that the package `doctrine/orm` is not satisfiable, because `nordsoftware/lumen-doctrine dev-master requires doctrine/orm ~2.6@dev`

Your options are:

- set the `minimum-stability` of all packages to `dev` (you already have that)
- or just add doctrine/orm and go lower in stability only on this package

  - by using `~2.6@dev` or `2.6.x-dev`

---

```
{
    "repositories":
    [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/flyandi/lumen-doctrine.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "nordsoftware/lumen-doctrine": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/orm":                "~2.6@dev"
    }
}
```