# How to add the component's version with specific tag from GitHub to PHP project using Composer

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php

I have GitHub repo [tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001](https://github.com/tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001)
 with example PHP component. This component does not have itself composer.json file.

My objective is getting this component to my project using project's composer.json.

I follow the [Julien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27970559/5598680) to [Contributing to open source bundles from vendor directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325158/contributing-to-open-source-bundles-from-vendor-directory/27970559#27970559)
I wrote composer.json that describes component as "package"

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
          "url": "https://github.com/tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001.git",
          "type": "git",
          "reference": "master"
        },
        "autoload": {
          "psr-4": {
            "TygrolewGmail\\Zawartosc\\Tworcy\\" : "src/Zawartosc/Tworcy/"
          },
          "files": [
            "/src/Zawartosc/Funkcje/_d.php"
          ]
        }
      }      
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001": "dev-master"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

It is installing the last commit from master branch.

```
$ php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001 (dev-master master)
    Cloning master

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

My repo history [gitk all branches history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R3TF.png)

```
fc70af [branch:master, no tag]
| 
|
|  9941b7 [branch:trial, tag:"v0.0.2"] 
| /
|/
c2849e [branch:master, tag:"v0.1"]
|
|
6f8ff7 [branch:master, tag:"v0.0.1"]
```

My composer.json file is downloading the last commit from master branch. But i want to install some previous versions of component or trial versions.

**How to install**

1. **The last commit from trial branch.**
2. **Commit with specific tag** (either from master or trial branch), for example "v0.1"

The Git repos have

- *branches*,
- *tags*
- and *commits*.

composer.json has fields:

- "version" inside "repositories"/"package"
- "reference" inside "repositories"/"package"/"source"
- version value after the package name in the "require"

What is their meaning and how do they relate to GitHub's branches, tags and commits?

## Edit

Flosculus answer worked, but I m still a bit confuzed. Correct me, if I do wrong, but I guess "repositories"/"package"/"version" has no connection with GitHub. However it must been used during Composer's "require".

On the other hand, "repositories"/"package"/"source"/"reference" could be anything that Git can checkout, it can be branch, tag, or commit's hash. I tried defining three items in repositories array.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001",
            "version": "dev-trial",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "trial"
            },
            "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                    "TygrolewGmail\\Zawartosc\\Tworcy\\" : "src/Zawartosc/Tworcy/"
                },
                "files": [
                    "/src/Zawartosc/Funkcje/_d.php"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001",
            "version": "0.1",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "v0.1"
            },
            "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                    "TygrolewGmail\\Zawartosc\\Tworcy\\" : "src/Zawartosc/Tworcy/"
                },
                "files": [
                    "/src/Zawartosc/Funkcje/_d.php"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001",
            "version": "1.2.3",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "fc70af"
            },
            "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                    "TygrolewGmail\\Zawartosc\\Tworcy\\" : "src/Zawartosc/Tworcy/"
                },
                "files": [
                    "/src/Zawartosc/Funkcje/_d.php"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
],
```

1. First defines version "dev-trial" as checkout trial branch which gives the last commit of that branch
2. Second defines version "0.1" as checkout tag "v0.1"
3. Third defines version "1.2.3" (non-existing  in the GitHub) as checkout commit "fc70af"

To get them I use respectively three requires

1. "require": {
       "tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001": "dev-trial"
   },

   2.

   "require": {
       "tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001": "0.1"
   },

   3.

   "require": {
       "tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001": "1.2.3"
   },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `VCS` type for repositories, Composer will scan each branch and tag for Composer files.  From there, based on the branch and tag names, it can assemble a list of packages.

These packages (like the one you created to reference that repository) exist on packagist.org, which is the default lookup for Composer.  The Authors of the repositories put them on Github.

In this case however, the repository is not on Packagist, and it has no composer file on any of it's versions.  So what you have done, is created a generic repository.  You can do the same thing with local directories, and zip files (local or remotely).  However your one is a Git repository.

See modified json:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "v0.0.1"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "psr-4": {
                        "TygrolewGmail\\Zawartosc\\Tworcy\\" : "src/Zawartosc/Tworcy/"
                    },
                    "files": [
                        "/src/Zawartosc/Funkcje/_d.php"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

When Packagist or Composer (Packagist also has a copy of Composer), scans a `VCS` repository, it flattens out all of the versions into multiple packages with the same name, but different versions.  In your case "references".  The modified json above uses `"reference": "v0.0.1"` to indicate a specific tag/branch.

https://github.com/composer/satis/issues/29

This is an issue requesting support for `VCS` repositories without composer files.  However it doesn't work.  When you modify the repository like so:

```
{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-php-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001.git"
}
```

This should work if the repo had the composer.json file.  In fact when you run `composer update` with this, you can see it searching each branch and tag.  But without the relevant composer file, all you will get is this:

> [Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]
>
> No valid composer.json was found in any branch or tag of
>   https://github.com/tygrolew-gmail/przykladowy-komponent-p
>   hp-tygrolewa-gmaila-0001.git, could not load a package from it.